# how can i select one of the options from database?

Tags: jsp

I want to select one of options which I extracted them from database then when user click on submit button redirect to another jsp page and print to him "you select ....".

```
<select>
<%
    while(rs.next())
{

        %>
        <option> <%= rs.getString("Competition_N") %>   </option>

    <%
 }
%>
</select>
```

Comment: "...."  means data extracted from db!

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide it to the `value` attribute and embed it into the `<form>`

```
<form action="second.jsp" >
<select name="selectOne"><%
    while(rs.next()){
        %>
        <option value="<%= rs.getString("Competition_N") %>"> <%= rs.getString("Competition_N") %> </option>
    <%
 }
%>
</select>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and in the second.jsp,

```
 <%= request.getParameter('selectOne'); %>
```

will get you the selected value from the first page

Comment: thanks , it's work . but if i want to show a message in second jsp that has data which i select from option in first jsp  , what should i do?

Comment: @user3871938 You need to print its value , updated my code . have a look at it